# Find a vector NOT perpendicular to a given set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

> Let us suppose to have a finite set of vectors $S=\{v_1,\ldots,v_m\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with $m \gg n$ in general). I need to find a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that is NOT perpendicular to any vector in $S$. The existence of such a vector $x$ is guaranteed, moreover almost every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies this property. But I need to find an algorithm to determine a vector with these properties, I cannot close my eyes and choose.

Any ideas?

EDIT1: in my case, the vectors in $S$ have some "symmetries" in the sense that they are generated by permutation and change of signs of a few vectors in $S$

EDIT2: $v_1+\ldots+v_m=0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$

EDIT3: I simplified the solution proposed by Tom Collinge. We define a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^m$ such that $x_m=x$ is what we are looking for. First define $x_1=v_1$, so $x_1 \cdot v_1 \ne 0$ and they are not perpendicular (obviously). Then, recursively, define for $k \in \{2,\ldots,m\}$
$$
x_k=\begin{cases}
x_{k-1}+2v_k & \text{if }x_{k-1}=-v_k\\
x_{k-1}+v_k & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$
By construction we have that $x_k \cdot v_i \ne 0$ for $i \le k$, then $x_m \cdot v_i \ne 0$ for all $v_i \in S$, so $x=x_m$ is not perpendicular to every element in $S$. Can it works?

> EDIT4: As pointed out, the algorithm proposed in EDIT3 does not work

Comment: EDIT2 doesn't help, as for any $v_1,\dots,v_{m-1}$ you can choose $v_m=-(v_1+\cdots+v_{m-1})$.

Comment: Choose $n$ random numbers as coordinates of $x$; the probability that it is NOT orthogonal to any of the $v_i$s is $1$...

Comment: @JeanMarie ok, but I need to find a deterministic way to compute such a $x$

Comment: @Bobech PRNGs are deterministic.

Comment: @JeanMarie Why do you say the probability is 1?   Why isn't there a minute chance that the random vector output is perpendicular to one of the input vectors?

Comment: @Spencer, "probability 1" doesn't mean it has to happen. If you pick a real number uniformly at random, then with probailitiy $1$ you won't pick the number $17$ – but you just might pick the number $17$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In a computer,  which is where the RNGs do their thing, there are no true real numbers, only rational approximations with a lower limit on granularity.  So, in practice the probability is a tiny bit less than 1.

Comment: @Spencer i don’t think the probability changes due to a computer. Even though the numbers being represented are rational on a computer, that doesn’t imply that the rational numbers that would make a perpendicular vector can be represented on the computer. I think it’s still with probability 1.

Comment: @EnricoBorba It does reduce the probability, because there are a finite number of values a vector can take. Given each vector has $n$ scalar components of $b$ bits, that's $2^{nb}$ possible values. The number of perpendicular vectors in this space can be tricky to calculate but there are at least $2^{n-1}$ of them; simply swap and/or negate components.   Assuming the RNG can caculate all the values,  there's at least a $1/2^{nb-n+1}$ chance that the generated vector can be perpendicular to any given vector. With M vectors the probability is $1-m/2^{nb-n+1}$.  Very close to $1$ but not quite.

Comment: @Spencer ah yes you’re right. You can just swap and negate components. For whatever reason I was having a hard time ensuring that there existed representable perpendicular vectors.

Comment: @EnticoBorba You can also assert a vector is "perpendicular" if it represents the grid cell where the real-valued true perpendicular would fall. I've been burned a number of times because of the effects of these "almost but not quite" vectors.

Comment: Proposed simplification in Edit3 doesn't work. Consider in $\mathbb R^2$  $s_1 = (1, 0): x_1 = (1, 0): s_2 = (0, 1), x_2 = (1, 1); s_3 = (-1, 0) \ne -x_2, x_3 = (0, 1)$ Then $x_3.s_3 = 0$. You need to ensure not just that $s_{n+1} \ne- x_n$ but that $x_n.s_i \ne 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that will work, although it might not work well in practice (because it might involve very large numbers). Reorder your vectors so that $v_2, \ldots, v_k$ are the vectors orthogonal to $v_1$, and $v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_m$ are not orthogonal to $v_1$. Recursively solve the problem for the vectors $v_2, \ldots, v_k$, so that you get a vector $y$ which is not orthogonal to any of $v_2, \ldots, v_k$. (If $k = 1$, i.e. there are no vectors in the set orthogonal to $v_1$, you can take any non-zero vector.)

Now define
$$
\alpha = \max\left\{\left|\frac{\langle y, v_i\rangle}{\langle v_1, v_i\rangle}\right| \mid i \in \{k+1, \ldots, m\}\right\} + 1.
$$
Then set $x = \alpha v_1 + y$. For $i \in \{2, \ldots, k\}$ we have
$$
\langle x, v_i\rangle = \langle \alpha v_1  + y, v_i\rangle = \langle y, v_i\rangle \neq 0
$$
by definition of $y$. For $i \in \{k+1, \ldots, m\}$ we have
$$
\langle x, v_i\rangle = \alpha\langle v_1, v_i\rangle + \langle y, v_i\rangle.
$$
Now if this were to equal zero, we would have 
$$
\alpha = \frac{-\langle y, v_i\rangle}{\langle v_1, v_i\rangle}
$$
which contradicts the definition of $\alpha$. Therefore $x$ is a vector which is not orthogonal to any element of the original set.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Now the difficult part is to build the correspondent algorithm

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it matters whether $m > n$ or not, and clearly we assume that $s_i \ne 0$ for any $i$

Define a sequence of vectors $(x_j)_ {j = 1}^m$ and constants $(\alpha_i)_{i = 1}^m$  as follows and then $x = x_m$ satisfies your requirement.

$\alpha_1 = 1; x_1 = \alpha_1 s_1$ and so $x_1$ is not orthogonal to $s_1$.

Given $k < m$ and $x_k = \sum_{i = 1}^k \alpha_i s_i$ and $x_k$ not orthogonal to any $\{s_i\}_{i = 1, k}$
Then for $i = 1, k + 1$ let $c_i = x_k \cdot s_i$  so that by non-orthogonality  $c_i \ne 0$ for $i = 1, k$.
If $c_{k+1} \ne 0 $ then put $\alpha_{k+1} = 0 \implies x_{k+1} = x_k$ and $x_{k+1}$ is not orthogonal to $\{s_i\}_{i = 1}^{k+1}$

Otherwise, chose $\alpha_{k+1} \ne 0$ and such that $\alpha_{k+1} s_{k+1} \cdot s_i \ne - c_i$ for $i = 1, k$
(which can be done even if $s_{k+1}\cdot s_i = 0$, since $c_i \ne 0$ for $i = 1, k$).
Then for $i = 1, k$,
$$
\begin{split}
x_{k+1} \cdot s_i 
  &= (x_k \cdot s_i) + \alpha_{k+1}(s_{k+1} \cdot s_i) \\
  &= c_i + \alpha_{k+1}(s_{k+1}.s_i) \\
  &\ne 0
\end{split}
$$

And for $i = k+1$,
$$
\begin{split}
x_{k+1} \cdot s_i
 &= (x_k \cdot s_i) + \alpha_{k+1}(s_{k+1} \cdot s_i) \\
 &= (x_k \cdot s_{k+1}) + \alpha_{k+1}(s_{k+1} \cdot s_{k+1}) \\
 &= 0 + \alpha_{k+1}(s_{k+1} \cdot s_{k+1}) \\
 &\ne 0
\end{split}
$$
So, $x_{k+1}$ is not orthogonal to $\{s_i\}_{i = 1, k+1}$

Comment: Maybe it could works in a simpler way: define $x_1=s_1$, then $x_1\cdot s_1 \ne 0$ for sure. Then, recursively, define $x_k$ as $x_{k-1}+2s_k$ if $x_{k-1}=-s_k$, otherwise as $x_k+s_k$. As you said $x_k \cdot s_i \ne 0$ for every $i \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$, so it should works, no?

Comment: I don't think that will work. If $s_{k+1}$ is orthogonal to $x_k$ then you need to ensure that $\alpha_{k+1}s_{k+1}.s_i \ne -x_k.s_i$ for $i=1, k$. I don't think $\alpha_{k+1}$ as a fixed multiple will achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can implement on a computer, perhaps the following would work.

Create an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, the rows of which contain your vectors.
Now pick a random uniform vector $b > \vec{0} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, for example by generating the entrees of $\vec{b}$ uniformly, and solve $A \vec{x} = \vec{b}$.

If any solution is found, you are done. If not, re-generate $\vec{b}$ and do it again.

If your assertion that practically every vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will do is correct, you will get a viable answer in a very small amount of tries.

Comment: If you are going the route of randomly generating vectors, you might as well just randomly generate $x$ and then check whether it is orthogonal to each vector in the basis directly. That cannot be slower than solving a matrix-vector system.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Definitely a possible approach as well

Comment: I need to find a deterministic way to find such a $x$, I have no interest in probabilistic method

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have non orthogonal vectors to get out of numerical problems with dividing numbers by zero, right?

If that is the case, try to maximize that value instead!
So solve the problem
$$b_{opt}=\max_{b}\left(\min_i(v_i^Tb)\right)$$

This should have a nice solution that you can always work with.

Comment: No, it is a problem that comes from combinatoric of torus action on a particular class of varieties